# USB headphones: how to use it correctly (streaming to usb-socket)?

Tags: usb, audio, headphones

I have a [headphones](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m956reYFoV1rqxrtco1_500.jpg) with **mini-usb** plug.
So, how to correct use it?

I need wire: **[audio - mini-usb](http://www.pdamall.ro/UserFiles/productPhotos/Cablu%20audio%20HTC%20miniUSB%20-%203.5%20mm%20AC%20A320_01121639.jpg)**.
After that i need to choose it as default sound-output device, am i correct?

Is it possible to stream audio to usb?
Can i use wire: **[usb - mini-usb](http://www.makingthings.com/store/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/5e06319eda06f020e43594a9c230972d/u/s/usb-mini.jpg)** to connect to computer and create usb-socket, that can stream audio to headphones?

Comment: We need to know the model of headphones to be able to answer.

Comment: sorry for quality :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stylized "B" rune on the bottom of the earpiece means that it's a Bluetooth device. The USB port is strictly for charging the internal battery, and you will need a Bluetooth dongle to use it with a machine that doesn't have a built-in Bluetooth adapter.

Comment: can i use it device with smartphone that has bluetooth, yes?

Comment: Should be able to.